# Faster alternative to apply() in pandas dataframe when np.where cannot work

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe with 600,000 rows that contains a date column. **The problem is that these dates are entered randomly as strings in 2 different formats:**

1. Strings in a pretty standard datetime format like "2018-05-07 04:28:45.970"
2. Strings in the UNIX datetime format like "1526366895249000000" (yep, down to nanoseconds but the precision is not a problem as all entries end in 000000)

Apart from these 2 formats, **there are also NaN values in the column**. I am trying to clean this column and convert it into a uniform datetime datatype.

I wrote the following function to do that:

```
def date_extractor(dt):
    # for UNIX format
    if str(dt).isdigit():
        return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(dt)/1000000000)
    # for nan
    elif type(dt) == float:
        return dt
    # for the common datetime format
    else:
        return datetime.strptime(str(dt), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Here is my call to the `apply()` function:

```
%time df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(date_extractor)
```

Clearly this is a very crass way of doing it. For example, in the function above, I have first checked for the UNIX format, then for NaNs, and finally for the datetime format. However, the vast majority of my date entries are in the datetime format. So for each iteration of the loop where the date entry is in the datetime format, the loop has to check against the first two if statements before finally reaching the final else statement. Because I don't know how to write a very efficient if condition specifically to check for the datetime format before checking for NaNs or UNIX format and without causing errors. Secondly, as you can see I have used the condition `type(dt) == float` to check for NaNs. If I use `isnan()` or `isnull()`, it will throw an error if the date entry is a string in the datetime format which is only checked at the end.

Pros, what are faster, better practices to follow?

Moreover, my code takes about 10 seconds to run through all the 600,000 rows. But I would also like to scale my code to data that is about 100 times bigger. How can I rewrite my `date_extractor()` function to accomplish this faster? I read that one way is to use a `numpy.where()` statement instead of `apply()` but my existing code will throw errors if written in numpy.where format.

Here is a demonstration of that (nested np.where):

```
np.where(str(df['Date']).isdigit() == True, datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(df['Date'])/1000000000), 
        np.where(type(df['Date']) == float, df['Date'], 
                datetime.strptime(str(dt), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')))
```

This throws a lot of errors - like calling `isdigit()` on an entire column, passing the whole column into `int()` function etc.

Tldr; **What is a better way (or maybe the best way) to clean my date column, keeping in mind that most of my date entries are in datetime string format like "2018-05-07 04:28:45.970", a few are in the UNIX format like "1526366895249000000", and a few are NaNs?** You can suggest a better code to use with my existing apply() function, or suggest a different method altogether.

Find sample data here:
https://github.com/verterse/experiments/blob/main/sample.csv

Comment: `apply` has a `raw` mode that can be lot faster, but I don't know if that's useful for you or not.

Comment: sample data would help... 10 or 20 rows that represent all three cases

Comment: @RobRaymond here you go [sample data](https://github.com/verterse/experiments/blob/main/sample.csv)

Comment: @hpaulj can you shed some more light on that? I am a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
df.date = (
    pd.to_datetime(
        pd.to_numeric(df.date, errors='coerce'),
        unit='ns',
        origin='unix')
    .fillna(pd.to_datetime(df.date, errors='coerce'))
)
```

##### OUTPUT(Based on the sample data):

```
                 VisitDateTime   UserID Activity
0 2018-05-15 06:48:15.248999936  U106593    click
1 2018-05-23 07:02:01.790000128  U108297      NaN
2 2018-05-10 06:28:53.391000000  U132443      NaN
3 2018-05-08 12:40:02.153000000  U134616    click
4 2018-05-11 15:35:43.689000000  U130784    click
```

Comment: Thank you! This gets the job done in about 6 seconds as opposed to 10 seconds earlier. However, it appears to be making small errors in measuring nanoseconds. For example if I pass '1526485332267000000' to your function, it returns a datetime of 2018-05-16 15:42:12.267000064 instead of 2018-05-16 15:42:12.267000 (an additional 64 ns). Any idea why this might be the case? I just noticed it is making similar additions/subtractions in the sample output you have provided too.

Comment: I added the format specifier ```'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'``` to the ```pd.to_datetime()``` inside the ```.fillna()``` method and reduced runtime from 6 to 1 second!